# Multi column Parallel sorting for List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

For a `List<T>`, I need to implement multi column sort, where column names and sort direction is known at run time. I use a `System.Linq.Dynamic OrderBy` API, which can take Column names and Sort direction as concatenated string, therefore following code works:

```
List<T> data = DataCollection; // Stored in Cache
var sortedData = data.OrderBy("Col1 asc, Col2 desc, Col3 asc,Col4 asc");
```

Challenge is when the size of data increase to `1 million+` records, then the same sorting operation slows down considerably, rightly so as there's no magic wand.

Now I am trying to understand is there a way for same operation in a `Parallel` mode. Following are the options, I am considering:

**Option 1:**

- Divide the data collection in smaller subsets like 100 K each and run the Sort on each, but then the challenge is how to merge the individual sets, In my understanding there's no convenient mechanism integrate sorted subsets

**Option 2**

As I was foraging for the options, came across the following parallel pattern for the `List<int>`, where recursive Parallel Sort also calls recursive serial sort internally:

```
public class CustomSort
{   
    // Fetch Partition
    public static int Partition(List<int> list, int left, int right)
    {
        int start = left;
        int pivot = list[start];
        left++;
        right--;

        while (true)
        {
            while (left <= right && list[left] <= pivot)
                left++;

            while (left <= right && list[right] > pivot)
                right--;

            if (left > right)
            {
                list[start] = list[left - 1];
                list[left - 1] = pivot;

                return left;
            }


            int temp = list[left];
            list[left] = list[right];
            list[right] = temp;

        }
    }

    // Quick Sort serial
    public static void QuickSort(List<int> list, int left, int right)
    {
        if (list == null || list.Count <= 1)
            return;

        if (left < right)
        {
            int pivotIdx = Partition(list, left, right);
            QuickSort(list, left, pivotIdx - 1);
            QuickSort(list, pivotIdx, right);
        }
    }

    // Quick Sort Parallel
    public static void QuickSortParallel(List<int> list, int left, int right)
    {
        if (list == null || list.Count <= 1)
            return;

        if (left < right)
        {
            int pivotIdx = Partition(list, left, right);        

            Task leftTask = Task.Run(() => QuickSort(list, left, pivotIdx - 1));
            Task rightTask = Task.Run(() => QuickSort(list, pivotIdx, right));

            Task.WaitAll(new[] { leftTask, rightTask });

        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a better way to achieve the same ?
- For integer its simple, how to translate my version of `multi column sort`, as selecting a partition will be a complex affair

Any pointer, that can set me on correct path

Comment: Have you tried PLINQ?

Comment: I'd be tempted to offload this to a database of some description to manage the indexing and subsequent sorting.

Comment: @Ivan you mean AsParallel, does that work with linq dynamic multi column sort, I haven't tried it

Comment: If you're using linq to sql, all LINQ does is forward the query to SQL Server. That's where all the processing will take place, and your code has no control over how the server does its sorting. The alternative is to get all the data into a `List<T>` and use a parallel sort of some kind--built in with PLINQ, if it's there, or something like what you posted. Whether that would be faster than having the server do it is something of an open question.

Comment: @Marc this is done on data in .Net memory cache,  have already taken it out of database, going everytime to database doesn't help performance. In memory is much faster

Comment: @Jim this is for linq to objects, I need to try PLinq if it has an option, thanks

Comment: Would something like `mylist.AsParallel().OrderBy(s => s.Col1).ThenBy(s => s.Col2).ThenBy(s => s.Col3).ThenBy(s => s.Col4)` work?

Comment: Your question is too broad as stated. It's not clear what you've tried or what your specific requirements are. I would expect `ParallelEnumerable.OrderBy()` to work (e.g. as @Jim suggests). More broadly, when you ask _"the challenge is how to merge the individual sets"_ it's true that this is not built into .NET as an exposed function, but "merge sort" is a standard and easily-implemented solution to that particular problem. Still, I'd start with `ParallelEnumerable` and only look at other examples if that doesn't work.

Comment: So how long does it take now to sort 1 million records?

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks that works beautifully.

Comment: @Evk that varies, depending upon the multi column sort requirement but easily goes up to 6-7 sec for even 1 column

Comment: @JimMischel if you post your comment as an answer at least I can Up-Vote

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your comment, I was not sure of PLinq ability to do Parallel sorting, which I have now understood and explored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most logical choice is to switch from LINQ to [Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx).

Unfortunately although `System.Linq.Dynamic` `OrderBy` method works, it actually hits `Enumerable` method overloads, thus has no effect on `ParallelQuery<T>` which requires binding to the corresponding `ParallelEnumerable` overloads. Also the Dynamic LINQ `OrderBy` implementation is using internal classes, so it's not possible to extend it externally (without source code).

Still a solution exists. You can use the following custom extension method. What it does is using Dynamic LINQ to build a fake query, and then replace the order related `Queryable` calls with the corresponding `ParallelEnumerable` methods using relatively simple [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static class DynamicPLINQ
{
    public static OrderedParallelQuery<T> OrderBy<T>(this ParallelQuery<T> source, string ordering, params object[] values)
    {
        var query = Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
        var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(ordering, values);
        var binder = new ParallelQueryBinder();
        binder.source = query;
        binder.target = source;
        var queryExpr = binder.Visit(orderedQuery.Expression);
        return (OrderedParallelQuery<T>)query.Provider.Execute(queryExpr);
    }

    class ParallelQueryBinder : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public object source;
        public object target;
        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Value == source)
                return Expression.Constant(target);
            return base.VisitConstant(node);
        }
        protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
        {
            if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
                return Visit(node.Operand);
            return base.VisitUnary(node);
        }
        static readonly string[] Methods = { "OrderBy", "OrderByDescending", "ThenBy", "ThenByDescending" };
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.IsStatic && node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && Methods.Contains(node.Method.Name))
            {
                var arguments = node.Arguments.Select(Visit).ToArray();
                var result = Expression.Call(typeof(ParallelEnumerable), node.Method.Name, node.Method.GetGenericArguments(), arguments);
                return result;
            }
            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use PLINQ services like this:

```
var sortedData = data.AsParallel()
    .OrderBy("Col1 asc, Col2 desc, Col3 asc,Col4 asc")
    .ToList();
```

and compare the performance.

Comment: Awesome works like a breeze thanks @Ivan, though I have realized in the process, PLINQ does an equally good job, thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome @Mrinal, glad to help collegue (felt kind of strange  seeing you at the questioning side:)

Comment: :), I do utilize the SO to its full capacity asking all kinds of questions, which I don't completely understand. In the process getting so many good solutions, which might not be possible if I just apply my mind. 
Using the community to its full potential.

Comment: thanks, do reach out in case there's change in plan :).